# Does Masquerade affect all players?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

Does a player who played the Masquerade card also have to pass a card or is it just all the OTHER players that have to pass a card?

Does the passed card go immediately into their hand or discard pile for all players?

Comment: Yes. To their hand. And it's interesting that Masquerade isn't an attack card

Answer (score 7):

The Masquerade card wording is (emphasis mine) -

> **Each** player with any cards in hand passes one to the next such player
>   to their left, at once. Then you may trash a card from your hand.

The card says 'Each' which will mean every player including the one who played it.  It does not say 'Other'

Compare this with the wording on the Witch card

> **Each other** player gains a Curse.

In that situation it is very specifically the other players.  If Masquerade meant to refer to just other players it would use the word other.

The card is 'passed' to a player's hand.  Note if it used the word 'Gain', it would mean it goes into your discard pile instead.